# Template Module location in TYPO3v12

Tags: templates, typo3, typo3-12.x

I'm new in typo3 and I installed typo3 version 12 on my  localhost but I have problem that I can't find the templates tab under web module in my control panel of the backend

This is the backend : [image]

i tried to install version 11 and it works but I want to know why I can't find it in version 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module has been refactored and split, see [Improved TypoScript and page TSconfig modules](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/12.3/Feature-100218-ImprovedTypoScriptAndPageTsConfigModules.html).

You can see it in your screenshot within the *Site Management* section.