# TYPO3: No template was found. View could not be section template

Tags: php, typo3, ddev

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2D2F.png)

Hello everyone, I've installed version 12.4.9, but I can't seem to find the 'template' section. I'd appreciate it if you could help me out.and I couldn't resolve my issue through the documentation either Thank you.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77257858/template-module-location-in-typo3v12 about the "Template" module.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the backend-module called "Template".
In TYPO3 v12 backend, there is the purple backend-module called "TypoScript".
There you can create TypoScript-Records as usual. For example the root-TypoScript record.